# EntityFramework 5 RC DatabaseGeneratedOption

Tags: entity-framework-5

I think is a stupid error from my part, but I can't find the solution.

I had EF4.3 with this configuring line

```
Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

with no problem. But when I updated to EF 5.0RC the same line get me an error
that says the type o namespace doesn't exist. ????

I didn't see any change about this in the RC !!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems like a kind of bug with VS or EF. Now, I closed the project, and I reopened it, and the error gone away.